# Automated Testing in Lollipop - waitForIdleSync stuck forever

Tags: android, automated-tests

Ever since I started using one of the newer devices from Google for testing, my tests have gotten stuck whenever we call `waitForIdleSync()`. When going over the documentation for espresso for another reason, I found this amazing tidbit: "To avoid flakiness, we highly recommend that you turn off system animations".  See [the main page](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/Espresso) and [how to do it programmatically](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/DisablingAnimations).

However, I've followed the instructions (disable animations and restart my device) and my tests are still getting stuck. Google's documentation has a habit of getting stale fast, so, is there something else I need to do to get this working on newer devices?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and it broke our tests completely for the last two days.

**Problem**

I researched this issue a lot. In fact it is an AOSP bug: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=82046 
(re-opened from this https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61111)

The problem occurs when you have a a animation, loading spinner, progressbar etc. in your Activity/ Layout that runs for a long time.

`waitForIdleSync()` will therefore wait forever.

In our case it is very problematic, because the methods `getActivity()`,`launchActivity()` and `launchActivityWithIntent()` of `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2`and also the new  `AndroidTestCase` have `waitForIdleSync()` inside.

**Solution Suggestions**

You can try turning the animations off or set the Visibility of any ProgressSpinner to `GONE` via an Intent Flag and start it with that. (Personally, I don't like that solution as it would affect the Activity itself and not the Testcode)

Another way would be to mock the preconditions for the Activity to let it not fall into this state.

Other suggestions are welcome!